# Android button click twice to receive click event

Tags: android, button, focus

I have set a button to `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to true (I need it to be focusable). Now when I click the button, the onCilck event cannot be triggered (it is gaining focus and ignore onClick event), only when I cilck again the onClick event will be triggered.

I found a solutions like this:

```
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    v.performClick();
                }
            }
        });
```

But this solution will cause some side effect as well, for example, if we click 'next' in the keyboard and jump focus to the button, onClick will fire. This is not what I want.

This issue is really anoying, is this a bug? Or it is intentional behaviour? Anyway to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Button needs two click for action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919849/android-button-needs-two-click-for-action)

Comment: I already mentioned I need the button to be focusable for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

set **focusableInTouchMode** false. Or just don't include that tag at all. Let it take its default value, whatever it is supposed to.

Comment: I already mentioned I need the button to be focusable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to avoid this issue by using the following code.

```
final View.OnTouchListener requestFocusTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !v.isFocused()) {
            v.requestFocus();
        }
        return false;
    }
};
findViewById(R.id.xxx1).setOnTouchListener(requestFocusTouchListener);
findViewById(R.id.xxx2).setOnTouchListener(requestFocusTouchListener);
findViewById(R.id.xxx3).setOnTouchListener(requestFocusTouchListener);
```